# ionic4 and firebase pushnotification issue

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm getting following error while building app:
ERROR: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.

In my android app, I have the following dependencies:

capacitor.build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.+"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+"
```

capacitor.build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
```

build.gradle:

```
try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```